# How to create a columns in two subcolumns

Tags: html

I'm creating a table in html and I want to obtain this result:

I created columns with their headers (S, Incoming, Session..) and rows with values (I retrive data from a Python script), but I can't to divide columns in "queue" and "block".

Answer (score 1):

Just add another row below your first header row. Your first row has 17 columns, 1 single + 8 double columns. In your second new rows, just make sure you add 17 single columns (ie without the colspan =2 attribute).

```
<tr>
    <th>1. xxx</th>
     ...
    <th>17. XXX</th>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an other row in the `thead` with all of the `th` you need:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Server</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">Incoming</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">Session</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">KPI</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">Export</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">Thresholds</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">AS Profile</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">MP Profile</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="padding-left: 0.5em">First Beat</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
    <th>queue</th>
    <th>block</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

I guess you could make these columns dynamically with the used templating language, if you don't want to hardcode them.

Comment: You are right! I try to create them dynamically.
By the way, thanks a lot for the help! :)